# Does the coefficient of a feature play a role in picking variables for linear regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

In general, when we do a linear regression, we keep only those variables that have p-values below 0.05 or 0.01. While eliminating those variables whose p-values are above our thresholds, do the coefficients of these variables play any role? Should we give some relaxed criteria to some variables with relatively large coefficients?

Let's say, I run a regression with $x_1$ and $x_2$ as my independent variables. $x_1$ has a coefficient of 1 and a p-value of 0.01, while $x_2$ has a coefficient of 100 and a p-value of 0.1. Should we probably keep $x_2$ in our final model, because of its relatively high coefficient?

For case of simplicity so that we don't need to worry about scaling, lets assume all variables are standardized.

Comment: Note that the magnitude of a coefficient depends on the scale of the variable. If I measured $x_2$ in meters, I would get a coefficient 1000 times larger than if I measured $x_2$ in kilometers.

Comment: Also, consider rewording the title slightly. The word "significance" is most often associated with "statistical significance" on this forum, while it has a somewhat different meaning in your question.

Comment: Do you intend to use your model to make predictions, or for some other purpose?

Comment: Do you consider picking variables by hand, or using some formal method (using information criteria, regularization, etc.)? The answer may depend on the method.

Comment: The relation between size and statistical significance of a coefficient also depends on the structure of the regressor. Moreover, if regressors are not linearly independent, it may not even be possible to associate a p-value with each of them separately.